# Notepad++ find and replace string

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I have about 1,000 lines that all look like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="MM_openBrWindow('this-part-varies.html','','width=270px,height=295px,top=150px,left=250px')"><img src="../images/image.jpg"/>
```

and I need to find each of these, and delete everything from "#" to "../images.

The only part that varies is the 'this-part-varies' file name.

I'm sure it's a simple regex line for some one out there!

Using notepad++ 5.9.3 on windows xp sp3.

Comment: What do you want the resulting string to look like? Can I assume there's a closing `</a>` tag that was left out?

Answer (score 0):

```
#" onclick="MM_openBrWindow('.+\.html','','width=270px,height=295px,top=150px,left=250px')"><img src="
```

I think that's it.

Comment: Tried this and x0r's code above, but none are recognised. I must be doing something wrong. I have a screen shot here: [link](http://min.us/mfgkmKChs). I'll play around, but please let me know if I'm doing something obviously wrong.

Really appreciate help, thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
  #".*"\.\./images
```

with nothing

Comment: Got to be careful tho, he could have a `<a href="#">...<9,999 lines of valid code>..."..images"...`